# Unit Testing state flow in viewmodel - stateflow only have the initial value, the values assigned later are not returned in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have two stateflow in my viewmodel

```
private val _peopleList = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<People>())
val peopleList: StateFlow<List<People>> = _peopleList

val _peopleListLoader = MutableStateFlow(false)
val peopleListLoader: StateFlow<Boolean> = _peopleListLoader
```

peopleList is used to display list and peopleListLoader is used to display progress indicator  in UI. All of these are working fine in app as expected. But in my Unit test when I check the `peopleListLoader` using `peopleListLoader.toList(values)` functionality its dosent have the values i assigned to it during the peoplelist loading.

Following is my implementation

PeopleListViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class PeopleListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val repository: PeopleRepository,
    @MainDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _peopleList = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<People>())
    val peopleList: StateFlow<List<People>> = _peopleList


    val _peopleListLoader = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val peopleListLoader: StateFlow<Boolean> = _peopleListLoader

    private val _peopleListErrorMessage = MutableStateFlow("")
    var peopleListErrorMessage: StateFlow<String> = _peopleListErrorMessage

        
    fun loadPeoplesList() {

        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {

            _peopleListLoader.value = true // set the loader visibility true 
            repository.getPeopleList().collect() {
                try {
                    when {
                        it.isSuccess -> {
                            _peopleList.value = it.getOrNull()!!
                            _peopleListErrorMessage.value = ""
                        }
                        it.isFailure -> {
                            _peopleListErrorMessage.value = it.exceptionOrNull().toString()
                        }
                    }
                }finally {
                    _peopleListLoader.value = false // set the loader visibility false
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Unit Test

```
class PeopleListViewModelShould {


    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    //SUT - PeopleListViewModel

    val repository: PeopleRepository = mock()
    val peoplesList = mock<List<People>>()
    val expected = Result.success(peoplesList)



    @Test
    fun turnLoaderVisibilityFalseAfterFetchingPeoplesList()= runTest{
        
        whenever(repository.getPeopleList() ).thenReturn(
            flow {
                emit(expected)
            }
        )
        
        val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()        
        val viewmodel = PeopleListViewModel(repository,testDispatcher)
        val values = mutableListOf<Boolean>()        

         val collectJob=    launch(testDispatcher){                
               
                viewmodel.peopleListLoader.toList(values)
            }
        viewmodel.loadPeoplesList()    
        System.out.println("Result is  : "+values.toString()) //This prints ony [false] iam expecting [false,true,false]       
       
        assertEquals(true, values[0]) // Assert on the list contents
        collectJob.cancel()       
    }
}
```

WHats is wrong with my unittest, I appreciate all suggestions and advance thanks to all..

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Same issue here